# Switching AI learning technique during training?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I'm thinking about creating an AI trying to play a game. However, it would take forever to learn by itself from 0. So I wonder if it would be possible to start the training with data from existing gameplay (from humans) and then switch to machine learning when the AI reach the point where it knows the basics.

If it's possible, is there an a way to do that with TensorFlow or should I do it from sratch?

Comment: It's always good to implement prior knowledge into an AI. However, I think it's difficult to track that human behavior and translate it into logic. Do you have additional information? I.e. what is the game what are the rules?

Comment: @SebastianR. The game is Rocket League so I guess we could say that there is not necessarily a ton of data to put as input (rotation, position of all players + ball) but the gameplay itself can get extremely complex.

Comment: Beside the Reinforcement Learning which learns on the fly. Google these keywords and you would find something suitable for your case: `Behavior Cloning` and `Imitation Learning`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the game is not complicated (i.e. open world) then you may be interested in deep reinforcement learning (you mentioned tensorflow), which does not require existing gameplay. It will start playing the game itself and gradually gather experience and develop game-winning strategies based on it. Other than that, using supervised learning to create your model sounds difficult and needs more clarification in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah, the game I was talking about is Rocket League so I thought that deep reinforcement learning would be too slow to learn from 0 that's why I was hoping to start with the AI trying to predict the moves of pro-player in games and then when the AI would be at the level of a pro or near, I would switch to reinforcement learning so it can learn by itself more complex stuff and not worry about the basics.

Comment: Aha I see. This can be problematic because unlike let's say chess you do not have access to all available information in a proper format (the features needed for your model are tricky - you mentioned position of all players, do you have access to their pos at any time so u can make decisions?). The only way I can think of is way too complicated using the information available to you is using CV to process the image in front of you but there are issues with this approach as well. I would recommend  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KSX2psajYrg but altogether sounds exteremely difficult task.

Comment: I heard there is a program/mod on the game called RLbot that can be used to code bot and you can get information like position, speed and more. This is useful as I could feed the AI with more useful information than RGB of pixels.

Comment: Yeah could totally use additional information for the final network. However, the user does not always have access to let's say the position for the rest of the players because they are not visible in the user's screen (as far as I know, I have never played the game) and thereforecannot be used in a realistic scenario.